# Replace Wishlist Button with Add to Cart

Tags: javascript, php, opencart

i am using opencart store , i want to replace add to wishlist button with add to cart in product page when i changed the code

CODE

```
        <div class="group-action clearfix">
          <div class="cart">
            <input type="button" value="Buy Now<?php //echo $button_cart; ?>" id="button-cart" class="button" />
          </div>
          <div class="btn-overlay cart">
                <input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_cart; ?>" onclick="addToCart('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');" class="button" />
            </div>
          <!--<div class="compare">
            <a class="pavicon-compare" onclick="addToCompare('<?php echo $product_id; ?>');"><?php echo $button_compare; ?></a>
          </div>-->
        </div>

      <?php if ($options) { ?>
      <div class="options">
        <h2><?php echo $text_option; ?></h2>
        <br />
        <?php foreach ($options as $option) { ?>
        <?php if ($option['type'] == 'select') { ?>
          <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option">
            <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
            <span class="required">*</span>
            <?php } ?>
            <b><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</b><br />
            <select name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]">
              <option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>
              <?php foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
              <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
              (<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>)
              <?php } ?>
              </option>
              <?php } ?>
            </select>
          </div>
        <br />
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($option['type'] == 'radio') { ?>
          <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option">
            <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
            <span class="required">*</span>
            <?php } ?>
            <b><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</b><br />
            <?php foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
            <input type="radio" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" id="option-value-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" />
            <label for="option-value-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
              <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
              (<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>)
              <?php } ?>
            </label>
            <br />
            <?php } ?>
          </div>
        <br />
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($option['type'] == 'checkbox') { ?>
          <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option">
            <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
            <span class="required">*</span>
            <?php } ?>
            <b><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</b><br />
            <?php foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
            <input type="checkbox" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>][]" value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" id="option-value-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" />
            <label for="option-value-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
              <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
              (<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>)
              <?php } ?>
            </label>
            <br />
            <?php } ?>
          </div>
        <br />
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($option['type'] == 'image') { ?>
          <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option">
            <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
            <span class="required">*</span>
            <?php } ?>
            <b><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</b><br />
            <table class="option-image">
              <?php foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
              <tr>
                <td style="width: 1px;"><input type="radio" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" id="option-value-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" /></td>
                <td><label for="option-value-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $option_value['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $option_value['name'] . ($option_value['price'] ? ' ' . $option_value['price_prefix'] . $option_value['price'] : ''); ?>" /></label></td>
                <td><label for="option-value-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
                    <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
                    (<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>)
                    <?php } ?>
                  </label></td>
              </tr>
              <?php } ?>
            </table>
        </div>
        <br />
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($option['type'] == 'text') { ?>
          <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option">
            <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
            <span class="required">*</span>
            <?php } ?>
            <b><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</b><br />
            <input type="text" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $option['option_value']; ?>" />
          </div>
        <br />
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($option['type'] == 'textarea') { ?>
          <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option">
            <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
            <span class="required">*</span>
            <?php } ?>
            <b><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</b><br />
            <textarea name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" cols="40" rows="5"><?php echo $option['option_value']; ?></textarea>
          </div>
        <br />
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($option['type'] == 'file') { ?>
          <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option">
            <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
            <span class="required">*</span>
            <?php } ?>
            <b><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</b><br />
            <input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_upload; ?>" id="button-option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="button">
            <input type="hidden" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="" />
          </div>
        <br />
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($option['type'] == 'date') { ?>
          <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option">
            <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
            <span class="required">*</span>
            <?php } ?>
            <b><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</b><br />
            <input type="text" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $option['option_value']; ?>" class="date" />
          </div>
        <br />
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($option['type'] == 'datetime') { ?>
          <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option">
            <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
            <span class="required">*</span>
            <?php } ?>
            <b><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</b><br />
            <input type="text" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $option['option_value']; ?>" class="datetime" />
          </div>
        <br />
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($option['type'] == 'time') { ?>
          <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option">
            <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
            <span class="required">*</span>
            <?php } ?>
            <b><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</b><br />
            <input type="text" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $option['option_value']; ?>" class="time" />
          </div>
        <br />
        <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>

      <?php if ($tags) { ?>
      <div class="tags"><b><?php echo $text_tags; ?></b>
        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($tags); $i++) { ?>
        <?php if ($i < (count($tags) - 1)) { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $tags[$i]['href']; ?>"><?php echo $tags[$i]['tag']; ?></a>,
        <?php } else { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $tags[$i]['href']; ?>"><?php echo $tags[$i]['tag']; ?></a>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>


    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="tabs-group">
  <div id="tabs" class="htabs"><a href="#tab-description"><?php echo $tab_description; ?></a>
    <?php if ($attribute_groups) { ?>
    <a href="#tab-attribute"><?php echo $tab_attribute; ?></a>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php if ($review_status) { ?>
    <a href="#tab-review"><?php echo $tab_review; ?></a>
    <?php } ?>

  </div>
  <div id="tab-description" class="tab-content"><?php echo $description; ?></div>
  <?php if ($attribute_groups) { ?>
  <div id="tab-attribute" class="tab-content">
    <table class="attribute">
      <?php foreach ($attribute_groups as $attribute_group) { ?>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2"><?php echo $attribute_group['name']; ?></td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($attribute_group['attribute'] as $attribute) { ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $attribute['name']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $attribute['text']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
      </tbody>
      <?php } ?>
    </table>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php if ($review_status) { ?>
  <div id="tab-review" class="tab-content">
    <div id="review"></div>
    <h2 id="review-title"><?php echo $text_write; ?></h2>
    <b><?php echo $entry_name; ?></b><br />
    <input type="text" name="name" value="" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <b><?php echo $entry_review; ?></b>
    <textarea name="text" cols="40" rows="8" style="width: 98%;"></textarea>
    <span style="font-size: 11px;"><?php echo $text_note; ?></span><br />
    <br />
    <b><?php echo $entry_rating; ?></b> <span><?php echo $entry_bad; ?></span>&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1" />
    &nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2" />
    &nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3" />
    &nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4" />
    &nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5" />
    &nbsp;<span><?php echo $entry_good; ?></span><br />
    <br />
    <b><?php echo $entry_captcha; ?></b><br /> <br /> 
  <img src="index.php?route=product/product/captcha" alt="" id="captcha" />
    <br />
      <br />
    <input type="text" name="captcha" value="" />
    <br />
       <br />
    <div>
      <div class="pull-right"><a id="button-review" class="button"><?php echo $button_continue; ?></a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
  </div>

    <?php if ($products) { ?>

  <div class="product-related">
   <span class="title-related"><?php echo $tab_related; ?> (<?php echo count($products); ?>)</span>
  <div id="related" class="slide" data-interval="0">
    <div class="carousel-controls">
      <a class="carousel-control left" href="#related" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
      <a class="carousel-control right" href="#related" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
    </div>
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <?php
    $max_related_column = 3; 
    if( isset($productConfig['product_related_column']) && $productConfig['product_related_column'] ){
        $max_related_column = $productConfig['product_related_column'];
    }
  $cols = $max_related_column;
    $span = floor(12/$cols);
  foreach ($products as $i => $product) { ?>
        <?php if( $i++%$cols == 0 ) { ?>
                <div class="item <?php if($i==1) {?>active<?php } ?>">
          <div class="row-fluid">
        <?php } ?> 
    <div class="span<?php echo $span;?> product-block">

      <div class="product-inner">
      <?php if ($product['thumb']) { ?>
      <div class="image">
       <?php if( $product['special'] ) {   ?>
      <div class="product-label-special label">
        <span><?php echo $this->language->get( 'text_sale' ); ?></span>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
        <a class="img" href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" /></a>
        <span class="mask"></span>
        <?php if( $categoryPzoom ) { $zimage = str_replace( "cache/","", preg_replace("#-\d+x\d+#", "",  $product['thumb'] ));  ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $zimage;?>" id="colorbox_<?php echo $product['product_id'];?>" class="img product-zoom" title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>"><span class="fa fa-search-plus"></span></a>
        <?php } ?>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var id = <?php echo $product['product_id'];?>;
                $('#colorbox_' + id).colorbox();
            });
        </script> 

        <div class="group-action">
          <div class="btn-overlay cart">
            <input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_cart; ?>" onclick="addToCart('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');" class="button" />                  
          </div>
          <div class="btn-overlay wishlist">        
            <a class="pavicon-wishlist" onclick="addToWishList('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');"><?php echo $this->language->get("button_wishlist"); ?></a>
          </div>
          <div class="btn-overlay compare">                       
            <a class="pavicon-compare" onclick="addToCompare('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');"><?php echo $this->language->get("button_compare"); ?></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      <?php } ?>
        <h4 class="name"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a></h4> 
        <?php if ($product['rating']) { ?>
        <div class="rating is-hover">
          <img src="catalog/view/theme/<?php echo $this->config->get('config_template');?>/image/stars-<?php echo $product['rating']; ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $product['reviews']; ?>" />
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($product['price']) { ?>
        <div class="price">
          <?php if (!$product['special']) { ?>
          <?php echo $product['price']; ?>
          <?php } else { ?>
          <span class="price-old"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></span> <span class="price-new"><?php echo $product['special']; ?></span>
          <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>

      </div>
    </div>
   <?php if( $i%$cols == 0 || $i==count($products) ) { ?>
   </div>
  </div>
   <?php } ?>

    <?php } ?>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <?php } ?> 

  <?php echo $content_bottom; ?></div>
  <?php if( $productConfig['product_enablezoom'] ) { ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src=" catalog/view/theme/<?php echo $this->config->get('config_template'); ?>/javascript/elevatezoom/elevatezoom-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 <?php if( $productConfig['product_zoomgallery'] == 'slider' ) {  ?>
  $("#image").elevateZoom({gallery:'image-additional', cursor: 'pointer', galleryActiveClass: 'active'}); 
  <?php } else { ?>
  var zoomCollection = '<?php echo $productConfig["product_zoomgallery"]=="basic"?".product-image-zoom":"#image";?>';
   $( zoomCollection ).elevateZoom({
      <?php if( $productConfig['product_zoommode'] != 'basic' ) { ?>
      zoomType        : "<?php echo $productConfig['product_zoommode'];?>",
      <?php } ?>
      lensShape : "<?php echo $productConfig['product_zoomlensshape'];?>",
      lensSize    : <?php echo (int)$productConfig['product_zoomlenssize'];?>,

   });
  <?php } ?> 
</script>
<?php } ?>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.colorbox').colorbox({
    overlayClose: true,
    opacity: 0.5,
    rel: "colorbox"
  });
});
//--></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"><!--

$('select[name="profile_id"], input[name="quantity"]').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=product/product/getRecurringDescription',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('input[name="product_id"], input[name="quantity"], select[name="profile_id"]'),
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#profile-description').html('');
        },
        success: function(json) {
            $('.success, .warning, .attention, information, .error').remove();

            if (json['success']) {
                $('#profile-description').html(json['success']);
            }   
        }
    });
});

$('#button-cart').bind('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('.product-info input[type=\'text\'], .product-info input[type=\'hidden\'], .product-info input[type=\'radio\']:checked, .product-info input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, .product-info select, .product-info textarea'),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            $('.success, .warning, .attention, information, .error').remove();

            if (json['error']) {
                if (json['error']['option']) {
                    for (i in json['error']['option']) {
                        $('#option-' + i).after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['option'][i] + '</span>');
                    }
                }

                if (json['error']['profile']) {
                    $('select[name="profile_id"]').after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['profile'] + '</span>');
                }
            } 

            if (json['success']) {
                $('#notification').html('<div class="success" style="display: none;">' + json['success'] + '<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/close.png" alt="" class="close" /></div>');

                $('.success').fadeIn('slow');

                $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);

                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow'); 
                window.location.href = 'index.php?route=checkout/checkout';
            }   
        }
    });
});
//--></script>
<?php if ($options) { ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/ajaxupload.js"></script>
<?php foreach ($options as $option) { ?>
<?php if ($option['type'] == 'file') { ?>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
new AjaxUpload('#button-option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>', {
    action: 'index.php?route=product/product/upload',
    name: 'file',
    autoSubmit: true,
    responseType: 'json',
    onSubmit: function(file, extension) {
        $('#button-option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>').after('<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/loading.gif" class="loading" style="padding-left: 5px;" />');
        $('#button-option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>').attr('disabled', true);
    },
    onComplete: function(file, json) {
        $('#button-option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>').attr('disabled', false);

        $('.error').remove();

        if (json['success']) {
            alert(json['success']);

            $('input[name=\'option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]\']').attr('value', json['file']);
        }

        if (json['error']) {
            $('#option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>').after('<span class="error">' + json['error'] + '</span>');
        }

        $('.loading').remove(); 
    }
});
//--></script>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('#review .pagination a').live('click', function() {
    $('#review').fadeOut('slow');

    $('#review').load(this.href);

    $('#review').fadeIn('slow');

    return false;
});         

$('#review').load('index.php?route=product/product/review&product_id=<?php echo $product_id; ?>');

$('#button-review').bind('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=product/product/write&product_id=<?php echo $product_id; ?>',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: 'name=' + encodeURIComponent($('input[name=\'name\']').val()) + '&text=' + encodeURIComponent($('textarea[name=\'text\']').val()) + '&rating=' + encodeURIComponent($('input[name=\'rating\']:checked').val() ? $('input[name=\'rating\']:checked').val() : '') + '&captcha=' + encodeURIComponent($('input[name=\'captcha\']').val()),
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('.success, .warning').remove();
            $('#button-review').attr('disabled', true);
            $('#review-title').after('<div class="attention"><img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/loading.gif" alt="" /> <?php echo $text_wait; ?></div>');
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#button-review').attr('disabled', false);
            $('.attention').remove();
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if (data['error']) {
                $('#review-title').after('<div class="warning">' + data['error'] + '</div>');
            }

            if (data['success']) {
                $('#review-title').after('<div class="success">' + data['success'] + '</div>');

                $('input[name=\'name\']').val('');
                $('textarea[name=\'text\']').val('');
                $('input[name=\'rating\']:checked').attr('checked', '');
                $('input[name=\'captcha\']').val('');
            }
        }
    });
});
//--></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('#tabs a').tabs();
//--></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/ui/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 6) {
        $('.date, .datetime, .time').bgIframe();
    }

    $('.date').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
    $('.datetime').datetimepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        timeFormat: 'h:m'
    });
    $('.time').timepicker({timeFormat: 'h:m'});
});

function display(view) {
    if (view == 'list') {
        $('.product-grid').attr('class', 'product-list');

        $('.product-list div.product_block').each(function(index, element) {
            html  = '<div class="right">';
            html += '  <div class="cart">' + $(element).find('.cart').html() + '</div>';
            html += '  <div class="wishlist">' + $(element).find('.wishlist').html() + '</div>';
            html += '  <div class="compare">' + $(element).find('.compare').html() + '</div>';
            html += '</div>';           

            html += '<div class="left">';

            var image = $(element).find('.image').html();

            if (image != null) { 
                html += '<div class="image">' + image + '</div>';
            }

            var price = $(element).find('.price').html();

            if (price != null) {
                html += '<div class="price">' + price  + '</div>';
            }

            html += '  <div class="name">' + $(element).find('.name').html() + '</div>';
            html += '  <div class="description">' + $(element).find('.description').html() + '</div>';

            var rating = $(element).find('.rating').html();

            if (rating != null) {
                html += '<div class="rating">' + rating + '</div>';
            }

            html += '</div>';

            $(element).html(html);
        });     

        $('.display').html('<span style="float: left;"><?php echo $text_display; ?></span><a class="list active"><?php echo $text_list; ?></a><a class="grid"  onclick="display(\'grid\');"><?php echo $text_grid; ?></a>');

        $.totalStorage('display', 'list'); 
    } else {
        $('.product-list').attr('class', 'product-grid');

        $('.product-grid div.product_block').each(function(index, element) {
            html = '';

            var image = $(element).find('.image').html();

            if (image != null) {
                html += '<div class="image">' + image + '</div>';
            }

            html += '<div class="name">' + $(element).find('.name').html() + '</div>';
            html += '<div class="description">' + $(element).find('.description').html() + '</div>';

            var price = $(element).find('.price').html();

            if (price != null) {
                html += '<div class="price">' + price  + '</div>';
            }

            var rating = $(element).find('.rating').html();

            if (rating != null) {
                html += '<div class="rating">' + rating + '</div>';
            }

            html += '<div class="cart">' + $(element).find('.cart').html() + '</div>';
            html += '<div class="wishlist">' + $(element).find('.wishlist').html() + '</div>';
            html += '<div class="compare">' + $(element).find('.compare').html() + '</div>';

            $(element).html(html);
        }); 

        $('.display').html('<span style="float: left;"><?php echo $text_display; ?></span><a class="list" onclick="display(\'list\');"><?php echo $text_list; ?></a><a class="grid active"><?php echo $text_grid; ?></a>');

        $.totalStorage('display', 'grid');
    }
}

view = $.totalStorage('display');

if (view) {
    display(view);
} else {
    display('<?php echo $DISPLAY_MODE;?>');
}
//--></script> 
<?php if( $SPAN[2] ): ?>
<div class="span<?php echo $SPAN[2];?>">  
  <?php echo $column_right; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php echo $footer; ?>
```

I also add some javascript Code  at bottom , but it doesn't work , Button gets changed but not a functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Check it (i didn't understand u r question)

From

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" class="btn btn-default" title="<?php echo $button_wishlist; ?>" onclick="wishlist.add('<?php echo $product_id; ?>');">
    <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
</button>
```

To

```
<button type="button" id="button-cart" data-toggle="tooltip" class="btn btn-default" title="<?php echo $button_wishlist; ?>" >
<i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
</button>
```

Ask me if you want something else